# Why is my php script not echoing the result into the original page?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, uploader

I currently have the following code, for a page containing an upload form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

</form>

<? include('uploader.php'); ?>
```

I then have the file uploader.php saved within the same directory. This file contains the following code:

```
<?php

if( $_POST ){
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path .time() .basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The  <a href=" . $target_path . ">file</a> has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

}

?>
```

My intention was to have it echo `"The  <a href=" . $target_path . ">file</a> has been uploaded";` on the same page, but instead it redirects to another page to display this message.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It redirects to the page used on the form action

Comment: Thanks, Dragon. I removed the form action bit and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try it:-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your form action set to uploader.php so everything happens there, so when you click on the submit button it will load that file and display your echo on that page, so thats different from the page where you started.